# how can i can i do update single or multiple document in multiple collection with single aql query

Tags: arangodb

I have two collections with the name "collection1" and "collection2" in database
I had created 1 view with name "myview" for search document in both collection

I have the following document in both collections
->

```
{
    "name": "Mac",
    "age": 23,
    "contry":"India",
    "abc":true
  }
```

This aql query is working fine if {"abc" : false} in collection2
 ->

```
FOR doc IN myview search doc.abc == true update doc with {"alive":true} in collection1 LET updated = OLD RETURN updated
```

but in my case, this condition is (abc == true) true in both the collection 
 so how can I do update single or multiple documents in multiple collection with single aql query

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you want, but would this query fix your issue?

```
FOR doc IN myview 
    SEARCH doc.abc == true 
    UPDATE doc WITH {"alive":true} IN collection1 OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
    UPDATE doc with {"alive":true} IN collection2 OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
    LET updated = OLD 
    RETURN updated
```

`OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }` will make the query pass even if the document is not in the collection.

Comment: this not working and throwing error                                                                      
                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
-> `Query: Index out of bounds (while executing) (exception location: /work/ArangoDB/arangod/RestHandler/RestCursorHandler.cpp:283). Please report this error to arangodb.com`

Comment: Hi darkheir Thank you for responding. But, i want to update in both collection using single aql query

Answer (score 0):

The query given by [**darkheir**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280608/darkheir) is working if we can do some changes like  use of update operation for one by one for both collections like this

for collection 1 ->

```
 FOR doc IN myview 
        SEARCH doc.abc == true 
        UPDATE doc WITH {"alive":true} IN collection1 OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
        LET updated = OLD 
        RETURN updated
```

and for Collection 2 ->

```
FOR doc IN myview 
    SEARCH doc.abc == true 
    UPDATE doc WITH {"alive":true} IN collection2 OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
    LET updated = OLD 
    RETURN updated
```

how to query for both collection in single aql query